# Meteor: Is there a way to cache map tiles for offline usage on the client (minimongo)?

Tags: javascript, meteor, openlayers, leaflet

I'm asking if there is a way to cache map tiles on the client side (Leaflet or OpenLayers, doesn't matter) with Meteor.

As far as i know tiles are saved as pngs. Is it possible to save these images on the client side (minimongo) or any other web-technology that fits to Meteor? These data files don't need to be synced with the server! I read that Mongo uses BSON which maximum document size is 16MB. Maybe vector tiles might fit better in the JSON pattern?!

I read about offline usage on this github-entry: https://github.com/awwx/meteor-offline-data and there are still some problem with offline data, but it sounds viable.

Looking for ideas -
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If leaflet uses png images, wouldn't it be browser's responsibility to cache them?

Comment: The browser already does this pretty well. If you store it in minimongo it could get inefficient. You would also have to store them as base64 and it would be very inefficient considering how large map tiles end up. Sometimes, per session its near 16-50mb